# Is the human mind only a limited store for sentences according to structuralists?

Tags: syntax

One of my teachers at the university told us that *Structuralists believe that the human mind is a limited store with a lot of sentences*

and I wonder to what extent this is true.

It is a bit "trivial" for me that De Saussure himself believed that the brain is a store of ready-to-use sentences, because it would be easy to refute this idea since the human mind is creative and can produce unlimited sentences (and sentences we never heard before) with only few rules.